# GeoServer Forcing to Download XML File Instead of Displaying in Browser

Tags: xml, rss, mime-types, geoserver, download

We have an old Linux box running GeoServer 2.0.1; in that there is a Layer which can output into RSS format. So if I were to access the following url in a browser:

http://myserver:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=topp:states&styles=&bbox=-124.73142200000001,24.955967,-66.969849,49.371735&width=780&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/rss+xml

then the server would display the xml file in the browser--as needed. However, we are trying to migrate to another machine--a Linux box. That is running GeoServer 2.4.4. In that server, a url like above prompts me to download the xml file. The same behavior exists in a Windows machine GeoServer 2.6.x.

So I tried the following in Geo Server: WMS->Allowed MIME types for a GetMap request->added application/rss+xml option but still no good.

What can I do to fix the problem? The old Linux server is too old, no documentation exists.

Thanks.

**Edit**: Something like this should work but doesn't: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.x/en/user/tutorials/georss/georss.html